# How to do error handling when creating AD users

Tags: powershell

I was having issues with my IF statement to check if my users already exist within AD , I have tried the Get-AD user is eq null however my IDE says that you cannot put null there. I was hoping in my script to loop through each user in my csv file and record the terminal output to my log and create an AD user if its not in the csv file. I have been scratching my head all day on how to achieve this

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Log_File = "C:\PS\Logs\$env:UserName_ad_script.log"
Start-Transcript -path $Log_File -append
if (Test-Path $Log_File) {
    echo "logging to $Log_File"
}
else {
    New-Item $Log_File -ItemType Directory
    echo "Log file created ....."
}
 
$ADUsers = Import-Csv C:\users.csv # or path of pyhton code
foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    $FirstName = $User.FirstName
    $LastName = $User.LastName
    $username =  $FirstName.$LastName
    $password = $User.passcode
    $Title = $User.Title
    $Manager_Email = $User.Manager_Email
    $AdUser_exists = Get-ADUser -Identity $username

    if ($AdUser_exists -eq null) {New-ADUser -Name $Name -SamAccountName $username -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-secureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) -Title $Title
        Enable-AdAccount -Identity $username
        Set-ADUser -Identity $username -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true    
    
    
    }
    else {echo "user already exists"}
    
    
     
    }
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: You might simply do a [`Try/Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally).

Comment: It's a typo, replace `null` by `$null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace() function to check for null.

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($AdUser_exists)) {
    New-ADUser -Name $Name -SamAccountName $username -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-secureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) -Title $Title
    Enable-AdAccount -Identity $username
    Set-ADUser -Identity $username -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
}
else {
    echo "user already exists"
}
```